# AS3 can't find the load method on a Loader

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I'm trying to load an image from the internet with AS3 following [this tutorial](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3loader/). When I try to compile the application I get the following error:

> Call a possibly undefined method load through a reference with static type Loader.
>
> ```
>       my_loader.load(where, loaderContext);
>                   ^
> ```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
package {
    import flash.system.ApplicationDomain;
    import flash.system.SecurityDomain;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.system.LoaderContext;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Loader extends Sprite {

        public function Loader() {
            var where:URLRequest = new URLRequest("image_from_web.png");
            var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain, null);
            var my_loader:Loader = new Loader();
            my_loader.load(where, loaderContext);
            addChild(my_loader);
        }
    }
}
```

In this page [compilerErrors](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/compilerErrors.html)(ErrorCode = 1061) says that this occurs when I try to call a method that does not exist.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.10 and compiling with ProjectSprout that uses the flex compiler.

Comment: better to change the class name Loader something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is namespace clashing (ambiguous class names).  The class you've posted is called `Loader`, yet you try to import another `Loader` class.  AS3 doesn't know what you refer to when you reference `Loader` now.    So it is looking for a `load` method on your custom `Loader` class (which doesn't exist).

To resolve the issue, either rename your custom class to something less ambiguous (`MyImageLoader` maybe, or whatever) - or use the fully qualified class path when referring to the display package Loader.  eg.

```
var my_loader:flash.display.Loader = new flash.display.Loader();
```